# React Scripts Not Found When Using GoLang http.FileServer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, go, directory

I am working on a Golang database project, in which I would like to use React to create the front-end. I am using react scripts linked to my index.html.

When I open my index.html directly, my react scripts work and the page is properly formatted. However, when I try to open the page through my server, the scripts are not found and I get a 404 error:

```
::1 - - [15/Feb/2017:16:16:24 -0500] "GET /build/react.js HTTP/1.1" 404 19
```

In order to access the index.html from my Golang server I use:

```
r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views")))
```

I am thinking the issue is with using the http.FileServer to access the html. I have tried locating my build folder in variety of locations, most recently within the views folder, always with the same result, that when opening the html directly the react scripts work, but they do not work when the html is accessed by my server.

Is there another method I should be using to accomplish this, or is it a problem with how I am organizing my dependencies?

Comment: Also important to note: I use Gorilla (https://github.com/gorilla/mux) for routing.

Comment: r comes from r := mux.NewRouter()

Comment: please post a gist with the code so we can reproduce it

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/epalaima/ecbbcf7494c898d4404aedb5fb769136

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the issue. I need to be able to serve the react scripts along with the html. Trying to figure out how to correctly add the r.Handle to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding:

```
r.PathPrefix("/build/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/build/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./build/"))))
```

in my main function in order to serve the react scripts. My file structure is:

```
 main.go
 views
 -- index.html (views/index.html)
 build
 -- react.js (build/react.js)
 -- react-dom.js (build/react.js)
 -- other react scripts...
```

Hope this helps anyone else who might be dealing with this problem.

Comment: It is a little different from my case where my built react app is published to a /public folder within the go app folder. When the main.go was run, all the HTTP requests were interecepted and the react page was not being reached. This helped me make request being served by react again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650343/how-to-have-golang-redirect-to-frontend-routing