# How to have golang redirect to frontend routing?

Tags: reactjs, go, react-router

Currently I am serving my react app using the following setup

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./build/")))
    http.HandleFunc("/my_api", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

and frontend

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/my_frontend_path">MyPath</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/my_frontend_path">
            <MyPath />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

But when I directly access `http://localhost:8090/my_frontend_path` from the browser golang returns `404 page not found`, is there a way to delegate any path not supported in `main` to default to frontend react router?

Comment: I can't quite grasp the idea. If you have a SPA, you never access directly anything but the path which serves the SPA's root and the HTTP "API" endpoint(s). To say that in other words, if a client's HTTP request hits the backend server, it cannot have any way to tell the client something like hey, _there_ is an _in-browser_ frontend app which you should visit instead—simply because the set of browsers which may be working with this backend server is unbounded, and the request might have been performed not using any browser to begin with.

Comment: I am doing this because I am implementing redirect for oauth2, and I want to redirect to a page that is not root, not sure if this is the best way to do it tbh, but I want to make sure that after oauth the user get redirect to another page

Comment: @kostix this has been a normal thing since the dawn of AJAX apps and JS APIs for browser URL rewriting to simulate page load state. SPA stands for Single Page, not Single URL. So if a user bookmarks a URL your main index has served, web servers have the ability to route all traffic to the index, eg. Apache's mod_rewrite and an .htaccess file. Nginx also has this ability through configuration. All user10714010 seems to want is this rewriting behaviour in Go without needing Nginx or any other reverse proxy in front of their go app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is covered in some detail in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually). Its worth reading through the answers (particularly the [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/11810946)) because there are a range of options (with varying downsides).

The basic issue is that when you make the initial request to `http://localhost:8090/my_frontend_path` your frontend react router is not running so the browser requests the page from the server; as `my_frontend_path` does not exist in the `build` folder `http.FileServer` returns a `404  page not found` error.

I suspect that the simplest solution for you may be to use hash history (covered in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/11810946)).

However as you have provided some Go server side code there is a fairly simple, purely server side, option. The "Catch-all" approach works by returning `index.html` (and hence your app) for any path that is not handled elsewhere. This means that your application will be loaded and the router should detect the `my_frontend_path` and act accordingly (this is why the contents of `index.html` is returned rather than a redirect). One way of implementing this simply is:

```
const FSPATH = "./build/"

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(FSPATH))

    http.HandleFunc("/my_api", func(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) { w.Write([]byte("API CALL")) })
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // If the requested file exists then return if; otherwise return index.html (fileserver default page)
        if r.URL.Path != "/" {
            fullPath := FSPATH + strings.TrimPrefix(path.Clean(r.URL.Path), "/")
            _, err := os.Stat(fullPath)
            if err != nil {
                if !os.IsNotExist(err) {
                    panic(err)
                }
                // Requested file does not exist so we return the default (resolves to index.html)
                r.URL.Path = "/"
            }
        }
        fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

As written this will return the contents of `index.html` if the file does not exist - this includes files like `favicon.ico`. If this is an issue you may want to add some limits (e.g. check the extension).

Comment: If stack overflow had a tip system (why dont they?) you'd be 10 bucks richer. Thank you so much, spent forever trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

just in case someone needs this with embedded files

```
//go:embed assets
var Files embed.FS


func frontendHandler() http.Handler {
  subpath, _ := fs.Sub(Files, "assets")
  fs := http.FileServer(http.FS(subpath))

  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
      fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
      return
    }
    f, err := subpath.Open(strings.TrimPrefix(path.Clean(r.URL.Path), "/"))
    if err == nil {
      defer f.Close()
    }
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
      r.URL.Path = "/"
    }
    fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```